# Question about Measure Theory "integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$"

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have this : 
$u_n\rightarrow u~\text{in}~L^{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ i.e., $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\Phi(|u_n-u|)dx\rightarrow0$
by measure theory, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $$\int_{B^c_R(0)}\Phi(|u_n|) dx\leq \varepsilon, ~\text{and}~ \int_{B^c_R(0)}\Phi(|u|) dx\leq \varepsilon$$

how to find this?

Edit: Where $\Phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ continuous,
convexe, even, increasing  and satisfy $\Phi(2t)\leq K \Phi(t), \forall t\geq 0$

Thank you

Comment: @saz i edited my question

Comment: @PhoemueX no, sorry i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

We start from the inequalities 
\begin{align}  \Phi\left(\left|u_n\right|\right) &\leqslant 
\Phi\left(\left|u_n-u\right| +\left|u\right|\right) \\
&=\Phi\left(2\frac{\left|u_n-u\right| +\left|u\right|}2 \right) \\
&\leqslant  K\Phi\left(\frac{\left|u_n-u\right| +\left|u\right|}2 \right)\\
&\leqslant \frac K2\left(\Phi\left(\left|u_n-u\right|  \right)+\Phi\left(\left|u\right|  \right)\right).
\end{align}
Now, fix $\varepsilon$ and consider $n_0$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}  \Phi\left(\left|u_n-u\right|  \right)\mathrm dx\leqslant \varepsilon /K$ if $n\geqslant n_0$. Then for any positive $R$ and $n$ such that $n\geqslant n_0$, 
$$\int_{B_R(0)^c}\Phi\left(\left|u_n\right|\right)\mathrm  dx\leqslant  \frac K2\left(\int_{B_R(0)^c}\Phi\left(\left|u_n-u\right|  \right)\mathrm  dx+\int_{B_R(0)^c}\Phi\left(\left|u\right|  \right)\mathrm  dx\right)\\
\leqslant  \frac K2\left(\int_{\mathbb R^N}\Phi\left(\left|u_n-u\right|  \right)\mathrm  dx+\int_{B_R(0)^c}\Phi\left(\left|u\right|  \right)\mathrm  dx\right)\\
\leqslant \varepsilon/(2K)+\frac K2 \int_{B_R(0)^c}\Phi\left(\left|u\right|  \right)\mathrm  dx.$$
To conclude, use the fact that for any integrable function $g$, $$\tag{*} \lim_{R\to  +\infty} \int_{B_R(0)^c}\left|g(x)\right|\mathrm dx=0 $$
to get what we want. For the second inequality, we only need (*).

Comment: But we need the integral on $B^c_R(0)$, the complement of the ball

Comment: And please what about $\int_{B_{R}^{c}} \Phi(|u|)dx\leq \varepsilon$

Comment: please can you answer me ?

Comment: The complement was missing everywhere. For the other part, see edit.

Comment: what is the theorem which gives (*)

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: How we get the complement of the ball ? please

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. What do you mean?

Comment: Is it oblige to have the integral on the complement or it is also right for the inergral on the ball ?

Comment: If you integrate over the ball and let $R$ going to infinity you get the integral of $|g|$ on $R^N$.

Comment: i don't understand , what happen then ?

Comment: $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{B_R(0) }|g| =\int |g|$.

Comment: and then we don't get the result ?

Comment: Yes, we do. $${}{}{}{}{} {}  $$

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Phi(|u|) dx <\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. But use (*).

Comment: please what is $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{{B_R(0)}^c}\Phi(|u|) dx$ ?

Comment: The limit is $0$ (take $g=\Phi(|u|)$ in (*)).

Comment: $\Phi(|u|)$ is integrable because it is continuous ?